# Make all list elements show one per line

Tags: python, list

I am using this code to make all elements of a list on per line:

```
ans = [multiplayer_msg, rockstar_msg, reddead_msg, crashbandicoot_msg, splitscreen_msg, codemasters_msg, wildewesten_msg, sports_msg, voor18_msg, september_msg] 
#strings

ans = ("\n""\n" "- ".join(ans))
```

The \n should do it on another line but when I run this, it looks like this:

[https://i.gyazo.com/231ce7d25951af57f380019e3db9ded2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxNgx.png)

How do I make the list elements show up one per line?

EDIT:

I am using www.pythonanywhere.com with Flask

This is my python code which "connects" to the html code:

```
return render_template("quizrezult_page.html", ans=ans)
```

And this is my html code:

```
<span>{{ ans }}</span>
```

Comment: `print('\n'.join([str(x) for x in ans])`

Comment: How are you displaying `ans` ?

Comment: I tried this, this is also how I am displaying it: 
ans = ('\n'.join([str(x) for x in ans])

        return render_template("quizrezult_page.html", ans=ans)
And then in html <span>{{ ans }}</span>

Comment: However that gives me a syntax error at the render_template line

Comment: If you're rendering it in html you need to use something like `<br>` tags instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the anaswers and comments it looks like you're using some templating system to output HTML. Well-behaved templating system will, by default, escape HTML markup (to avoid unsafe markup injection). You could of course tell your template system to not escape this particular content, BUT this is not the best solution, by far: the whole point of using a template is to format your content within the template and keep the Python code free of markup.

IOW, you should not concatenate your list content in the python code but use the template itself to render it. You didn't specify which template engine you're using (well, you didn't even mention any templating at all in your question, which would have saved everyone's time...) but in Django this could look something like (`answers` being your list):

```
{% for answer in answers %}
<p>
  {{ answer }}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT : ok so you're using Flask. If you read [Flask's doc on templates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/templates/), the first thing you read is (emphasis is mine):

> The templates are using Jinja2 syntax and **have autoescaping enabled by default**. This means that **unless you mark a value in the code with Markup or with the |safe filter in the template, Jinja2 will ensure that special characters such as < or > are escaped with their XML equivalents**.

This being said, my advice still holds: DO NOT build your html in Python code, use your template engine instead, that's what it is for. Jinja2 syntax comes from Django templates so my above snippet should work as is or with only minor modifications - but you may want to change the markup to use a bullet list or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(*ans, sep='\n')
```

Should work for you

Comment: That gives me a syntax error. By the way, I don't need to print it. I need the variable 'ans' to show multiple lines of text.

Answer (score 1):

If you're rendering it in html, `\n` won't have any effect. You could try using `<br>` tags.

```
ans = '<br>'.join(ans)
```

Though if you're actually trying to make a bullet list, you might consider using `<ul>`. e.g.

```
ans = '<ul><li>' + '</li><li>'.join(ans) + '</li></ul>'
```

Comment: I put that in python, but it returned this: https://i.gyazo.com/e0b64bafcd9ab87c4229f8be4edf9d39.png you literally see <br>

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn it looks like you're using some templating system which by default escapes html (which is the right thing to do actually).

Comment: I am using pythonanywhere.com. But I still dont know what to do.

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn That would have been useful information to put in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I will change it.

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn pythonanywhere is an hosting solution not a framework. What framework (and template engine) are you using ? Django ? Flask ? Bottle ? Something else ?